# Task Manager Module

Tags: python, python-module, taskmanager

I was wondering if there is a module that allows the program to see what tasks are running. For example, if I am running Google Chrome, Python Idle, and the program, it should see all 3. (It is most important that it can see its self.)

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/psutil/

Comment: Good. I can't give you reputation though unless you ask it as a question.

Comment: Ok, let it not be unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**psutil**](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/)

> psutil is a module providing an interface for retrieving information on all running processes and system utilization (CPU, disk, memory, network) in a portable way by using Python.

Comment: Oh ya, in case you where wondering, I needed a module like this, so I could make a program find information on its self, and therefore become self aware.